# react router state when iframe in page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, redux, react-redux

I have a single page with react, router and redux

but inside that page, I'm opening an iframe from the same app

The problem is when I do stuff that change the route in the iframe, they change the parent page.

It feels like the iframe page changes the parent.

Code example:

```
<SomePage>
   <div>dont care</div>
   <iframe src="same-url.com/just_another_page" />
</SomePage>
```